# Creación de paquetes en Python

Tags: python

últimamente estuve teniendo problemas con la instalación y creación de paquetes (En Python). En primer lugar, por alguna razón, no se me crean carpetas caché cuando defino un paquete con el archivo __ init __.py, cosa que siempre pasaba. Luego viene el problema de la instalación (porque crear uno, se ve, no es un problema):

El código de CMD:

```
Microsoft Windows [Versión 10.0.18363.959]
(c) 2019 Microsoft Corporation. Todos los derechos reservados.

C:\Users\Usuario>desktop
"desktop" no se reconoce como un comando interno o externo,
programa o archivo por lotes ejecutable.

C:\Users\Usuario>cd desktop

C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop>python setup.py sdist
running sdist
running egg_info
creating paquetefinal.egg-info
writing paquetefinal.egg-info\PKG-INFO
writing dependency_links to paquetefinal.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
writing top-level names to paquetefinal.egg-info\top_level.txt
writing manifest file 'paquetefinal.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
reading manifest file 'paquetefinal.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'paquetefinal.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
warning: sdist: standard file not found: should have one of README, README.rst, README.txt, README.md

running check
warning: check: missing required meta-data: url

creating paquetefinal-1.0
creating paquetefinal-1.0\Paquetesdistribuidores
creating paquetefinal-1.0\paquetefinal.egg-info
copying files to paquetefinal-1.0...
copying setup.py -> paquetefinal-1.0
copying Paquetesdistribuidores\1modulo.py -> paquetefinal-1.0\Paquetesdistribuidores
copying Paquetesdistribuidores\__init__.py -> paquetefinal-1.0\Paquetesdistribuidores
copying paquetefinal.egg-info\PKG-INFO -> paquetefinal-1.0\paquetefinal.egg-info
copying paquetefinal.egg-info\SOURCES.txt -> paquetefinal-1.0\paquetefinal.egg-info
copying paquetefinal.egg-info\dependency_links.txt -> paquetefinal-1.0\paquetefinal.egg-info
copying paquetefinal.egg-info\top_level.txt -> paquetefinal-1.0\paquetefinal.egg-info
Writing paquetefinal-1.0\setup.cfg
creating dist
Creating tar archive
removing 'paquetefinal-1.0' (and everything under it)

C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop>cd dist

C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\dist>pip3 install paquetefinal-1.0.tar
WARNING: Requirement 'paquetefinal-1.0.tar' looks like a filename, but the file does not exist
Processing c:\users\usuario\desktop\dist\paquetefinal-1.0.tar
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\Usuario\\Desktop\\dist\\paquetefinal-1.0.tar'


C:\Users\Usuario\Desktop\dist>
```

Comment: Hola Joaquín, el error te indica que el archivo `paquetefinal-1.0.tar` no existe dentro del directorio `dist` de tu escritorio. Haz `dir` dentro de la carpeta `dist`y comprueba que existe el archivo

Comment: Sí, el archivo existe. Fíjate en CMD, cuándo se crea el paquete saltan algunos errores, quizá tenga que ver con eso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es posible que tu archivo no exista y si lo estás haciendo en windows te sugiero que hagas un `dir` en consola para que te liste los archivos dentro de la carpeta `dist`.

Creo que lo más probable sea que te falte la extensión gzip, y tu archivo se llame realmente `paquetefinal-1.0.tar.gz`, o al menos ese el comportamiento por defecto de `distutils`. Un saludo

Comment: Ahora voy a probar. Y sí, tenés razón, normalmente viene con la extensión .gz

Comment: Genial, si me atrevo a adivinar diría que tu gestor de archivos comprimidos en Windows reconoce la extensión .gz y si tienes activa la opción de explorer de ocultar las extensiones conocidas es probable que te hayas confundido. Por eso te decía de hacer `dir` que lista todos los archivos y carpetas íntegramente. Un saludo